# PostgreSQL function returns type does not exist when called from C#

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Here is the example function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Membership".status2(membershipid text)
RETURNS "Membership".memberstatus
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
_membershipStatus MemberStatus;
total integer;
typeId integer;
startDate date;
endDate date;
groupId integer;
membershipStatus varchar;
BEGIN
Select "TypeId", "StartDate","EndDate" into typeId, startDate, endDate from     "Membership"."Memberships" M where M."MembershipId" = membershipId;

   if endDate > NOW() then
   _membershipStatus.groupid = 3;
   _membershipStatus.membershipstatus = 'Expired';
   end if;

RETURN _membershipStatus;
END;
$function$
;
```

This works fine when yesterday I called via

```
select status2('gwgwg');
```

Today I start the implementation and suddenly when called using

```
select "Membership".status2('sdgsd');
```

I am getting

> SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "memberstatus" does not exist

Of course I've tried to add "Membership".memberstatus but same result.

Nothing was changed since yesterday and when I was testing it, it was working fine.

I can't understand why it would disappear again???

I already had this problem, and for some reason after a while all the data types were disappearing (after working fine for X minutes). They are still in schema data types, but aren't found... (?)

BTW 
When I try to delete the data type, I will get information that the function depends on it... Yet function won't find it (it was working fine at first).

Comment: I strongly recommend to never use double quotes in SQL statements.

Comment: I would wish, but often it won't find schema / table without it. I've found that with double quotes the problem doesn't exist

Comment: you sholdn't create them using double quotes to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume it is a `search_path` problem.

Either change the declaration

```
_membershipStatus MemberStatus;
```

so that the data type is schema qualified (`"Membership".memberstatus`), or set the `search_path` in the function definition:_membershipStatus MemberStatus;

```
ALTER FUNCTION "Membership".status2(text) SET search_path = "Membership";
```

Your SQL would be less complicated if you didn't use mixed case identifiers.

The reason why it worked fine for a while must be that you had the `search_path` set in the session.

Comment: I have tried to add full schema name.

Query is executed but function doesn't change at all in that part of the code.

The search path trick worked ! THANK YOU !

Comment: Can you explain that comment? I don't understand it. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Sure, basically I have changed the _membershipStatus MemberStatus; to _membershipStatus "Membership".MemberSatus; After running it it wasn't altered. I've removed the function and recreated using new code, and the same happened "Membership". was missing (however was in place in other parts of a code). I just start using PostgreSQL and seems like my software is acting weird (one time works, other time doesn't something, etc). 

As the problem, one time it was finding the MemberStatus, after 20-30 minutes wasn't (same window, same instance of the app).

Comment: Oh, yes the problem is solved by setting search_path.